# Eliminate string elements in a list with double 'a'

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I've been trying to create a program that will verify if a string inside a list, or the element of that list contains 2 or more 'a', in case it doesn't it should save the element in a new list. This is my code so far:

```
ent = input("Ingresa un listado de palabras separados por coma: ")
lst_1 = ent.split(",")
lst_2 = []

def cuenta(lst_M):
    tmp = 0
    for i in range (0,len(element)):
        print(lst_M[i])
        if lst_M[i] == 'a':
            tmp += 1
            print(tmp)
    return tmp    


for element in lst_1:
    lst_rev = [i for i in element]
    cuenta(lst_rev)
    print("Este es el valor de tmp:",tmp)
    if tmp <= 2:
        lst_2.append(element)
    print(lst_2)

print(lst_2)
```

The output looks something like this:

```
Ingresa un listado de palabras separados por coma: ana,another,person,ana
a
1
n
a
2
Este es el valor de tmp: 0
['ana']
a
1
n
o
t
h
e
r
Este es el valor de tmp: 0
['ana', 'another']
p
e
r
s
o
n
Este es el valor de tmp: 0
['ana', 'another', 'person']
a
1
n
a
2
Este es el valor de tmp: 0
['ana', 'another', 'person', 'ana']
['ana', 'another', 'person', 'ana']
```

As you can see I use a function to calculate the number of 'a' inside the element, but for some reason the variable tmp outside the function is always 0.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to store the return value of the `cuenta` method in your `for` loop: `tmp = cuenta(lst_rev)`. Then check the return value.

Comment: It totally worked, can u put it as an aswer so I can accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning the result of the function call to a variable. Currently you are calling the function which is returning a value but you aren't "capturing" the return value outside the scope of the function call.

```
tmp = cuenta(lst_rev)
print("Este es el valor de tmp:",tmp)
```